# use fetch API and event handler

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I loaded my local .json file with fetch, and I registered an event handler on a button element.

Here is my code:

```
        let tagName;
        function start(){
            fetch("./product.json")
            .then(response=>response.json())
            .then(data=>addItem(data,tagName))
            .catch(error=>console.log(error));            
        }
        start();
        
        function addItem(data,tagName){                
            var container = document.getElementById("itemBox");
            for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){                       
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                var img = data[i].itemImg;                                  
                div.className = "imgBox";
                div.innerHTML = "<img src= "+img+">";
                container.appendChild(div);
            }
        };
        
        let tagBtn = document.getElementById("tagsubmit");
        tagBtn.onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById("tmp").innerHTML = "HELPME";
        }
```

When I opened this html file, json file is loaded&rendered succesfully, but the button with event handler doesn't work.

How can I make both of them work successfully?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Provide a [mcve] (where's the HTML?).

Comment: What are the errors in the console?

Comment: @RichieBendall uncaught TypeError : Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick').

Comment: @Quentin I'm sorry... I am not used to stackoverflow and I'm not from anglosphere, so I'm not much good at English.

Comment: The script can't find an element in the dom with the ID "tagsubmit". Check that one exists and that the script is executed after it is added.

Comment: @RichieBendall Thank you for your answer! I'll check and retry.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the event delegation feature, like this:

```
document.getElementById('itemBox').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.id === 'tagsubmit') {
        document.getElementById('tmp').innerHTML = 'HELPME';
    }
});
```

Nice tutorial by Dmitri Pavlutin:
https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/